# Como criar um botão na API do google maps para adicionar marcador?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-location-api

A dúvida é a seguinte...

Dei uma pesquisada por uns dias antes de vir aqui, mas só acho como adicionar o marcador de forma manual igual ao exemplo do google:

```
// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));   

Map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Sydney));
```

mas gostaria de criar um botão na API do maps, que quando clicado adiciona o marcador na minha posição atual, e caso eu mude de lugar e clique novamente nesse botão adiciona outro marcador e assim por diante.

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente, o que você quer então é como obter sua localização atual e mantê-la sempre atualiza, já que a forma de adicionar o marcador você já tem, certo?

A recomendação é utilizar o [`FusedLocationProviderApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), do **Google Play Service**. Então o primeiro passo é adicioná-lo ao seu arquivo `build.gradle`, caso ainda não tenha nas dependências do seu projeto:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Em sua *Activity*, precisamos iniciar o `GoogleApiClient` e ficar *"escutando"* as atualizações de localização do usuário. Primeiro, implemente o seguinte:

```
public class MapaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
```

Declare o objeto nas propriedades de sua *Activity*:

```
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

E este método abaixo você pode iniciá-lo no `onCreate`:

```
private void startTracking() {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Google Play Services.");
    }
}
```

Aqui você está iniciando o **GoogleApiClient**, e com o sucesso, aí sim você solicita a atualização das coordenadas do usuário. Abaixo os métodos que precisam ser implementados de acordo com as interfaces que incluímos na assinatura da *Activity*:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    stopLocationUpdates();
}
```

Aqui quando a latitude e longitude do usuário é obtida, você pode guardá-la para utilizar quando o botão de adicionar marcador for acionado.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        // Localização atual obtida
    }
}
```

Esse método você aciona quando finalizar a *Activity*, para encerrar o processo de atualização da localização e desconectar o *client*.

```
private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

---

Nesta implementação, enquanto sua *Activity* estiver ativa, a localização sempre será requisitada de acordo com o intervalo definido. Outra opção é você somente solicitar a localização atual quando o botão for acionado, chamando o `requestLocationUpdates` e parando logo quando for obtida.

Basta você definir qual das duas opção se encaixa melhor de implementar da melhor forma. Um exemplo mais completo você pode ver **[aqui](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)**, do próprio *Google*.

Comment: Creio que minha pergunta não ficou muito clara, o que tenho duvida é em como criar um botão que toda vez seja clicado adicione um marcador na sua posição atual

Comment: Ficou claro sim, mas isso envolve todo esse processo de buscar a localização, que como você não mencionou, imagino que também faça parte da sua dúvida. Enfim, o botão propriamente dito, nada mais é do que implementar o método `setOnClickListener` e assim executar o processo do início. Ou através do `android:onClick` do seu layout. O que mais além disso?

Comment: Bom, fiz o botão dessa forma 

`public void adicionarMarker(View view) {

        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng posicao = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.position(posicao);
                marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
            }
        });
    }`

porem ele não ta encerrando, criar um marcador sem eu clicar nele